# ExceptionMapper provider not working with jersey

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jersey-2.0

I'm doing a Webservice in java using Jersey.
my dependencies for jersey are:

```
/* JAX-RS Impl (Jersey) */
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.27'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.27'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-sse:2.27'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.27'

//Jackson implementation 
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.27'

// Hateoas
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-declarative-linking:2.27'

//Jersey Impl test
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:2.27'

compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
```

My class Exception looks like the next snippet, I'm catching all Throwable to test this works.

```
package com.apporelbotna.appuestas.rest.exception;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class WebserviceExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>
{
    public WebserviceExceptionMapper()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm getting created!!! - WebserviceExceptionMapper");
    }

    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex)
    {
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }
}
```

And my rest Endpoint looks like:

```
@GET
public Response getUsers() throws Exception
{
    throw new Exception("Hi i'm crashing!");
}
```

I read the documentation of Jersey and i undestand that i can register the exception mappers using @provider in the class. But the application doesn't recognize the class. I tried to register my class in my ResourceConfig class. And this it works.

```
@Provider
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webservice")
public class RestResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    @Context
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.getInitParameter("system.info.allow");
        }
    }

    public RestResourceConfig()
    {
        // Register components in a package
        register(WebserviceExceptionMapper.class);
        packages("com.apporelbotna.appuestas.rest.endpoint");
    }
}
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

`packages("com.apporelbotna.appuestas.rest.endpoint")` This tells Jersey which package(s) to scan for `@Provider` and `@Path` classes and register them. You can list multiple packages or you can just use a base package like `com.apporelbotna.appuestas` and Jersey will scan the package recursively.

So if you want your `ExceptionMapper` to be registered automatically, do one of the following

```
packages("com.apporelbotna.appuestas.rest.endpoint",
         "com.apporelbotna.appuestas.rest.exception");
// -or-
packages("com.apporelbotna.appuestas.rest");
```

Comment: So what is the point to use the anotation? I thought that was to avoid register in ResourceConfig. If you add the anotation you need to register anyway?

Comment: Because the scan only picks up classes with the annotations. I stated this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I was banging my head for the same answer, and could not find it in the documentation.

Comment: ExceptionMapper<Throwable> doesn't work for some reason, ExceptionMapper<Exception> and ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> works, need to check in detail.

Comment: This is absolutely helpful. To be clear, you need create an `ResourceConfigCustomizer` bean to append more `packages` to scan. Since there might be too many classes, 5000+ for example, fully scanning may take too long for a quick-start/stop application. To specify packages is reasonable.