# ExceptionMapper in embedded Camunda 7 : io.file.FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, camunda

We have embedded Camunda 7 in our own Spring Boot(version 2.7.10) application and we need customize `ExceptionMapper` to add customized branch to handle some special `Exception`.

Thanks to [ExceptionMapper provider not working with jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050115/exceptionmapper-provider-not-working-with-jersey/53167816#53167816), we could firstly added our own `ExtendedRestExceptionHandler`(extends from `RestExceptionHandler`) and our `Spring Boot` application runs fine in `IntellijIDEA 2023.1` as a `Spring Boot` application but failed when runs as a fat jar:

```
java -jar ${JAVA_OPTS} camunda-application.jar ${ARGUMENTS}
```

When runs as a fat jar, the application fails with exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: camunda-application.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1161) ~[na:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.getInputStream(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:154) ~[jersey-server-2.35.jar!/:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:64) ~[jersey-server-2.35.jar!/:na]
    ... 130 common frames omitted
```

After digging into the exception, we found `org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory#create` just treat the whole `URL` without rest from its last `!` as a normal file `URL` and try to loaded it as `FileInputStream`, which not absolutely right. Suppose we got a `URL` as `camunda-application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/engine.jar!/path/to/ExtendedRestExceptionHandler.class`, the whole URL without rest after last `!` should be `camunda-application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/engine.jar`. It's obviously an embedded `jar` that could not be treated as an external `jar` file.

So, what should be the right way to make our customized classes can be scanned by `jersey` and Camunda 7?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the source code of `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig#packages(java.lang.String...)`, I found it actually use `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig#registerFinder` to scan all candidates. So my final solution is use it too.

Instead of adding additional packages to scan customized classes, we try registering `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceFinder` to `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` directly. In our `ResourceFinder`, we can use `Spring` tools `org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver#getResources` to load our customized extensions. Such as:

```java
            String resourcePattern = "**/*.class";
            String packageSearchPath = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX +
                resolveBasePackage(basePackage) + '/' + resourcePattern;
            Resource[] scanned = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(packageSearchPath);
            logger.info("Scanned {} classes under {}", scanned.length, basePackage);
            return Stream.of(scanned);
```

This could solve our problem.